# Image Upload not working, iOS Swift Multipart

Tags: swift, alamofire, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I have to upload an image to the server, but i am getting unusual behaviour,

```
if let imgdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "vishal"), 0.2) {

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "token": authToken,
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        ]

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(imgdata, withName: "image", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .patch, headers: headers) { (result) in
            switch result{
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print("Succesfully uploaded")
                    if let _ = response.error{
                        return
                    }
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        print(json)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

in a new project, this code works fine and uploads the image to the server, but in my old project for the same code, api call is successful but image is not uploaded

Please help

Comment: Method type is patch it will be put or post.

Comment: exact code works fine in the new xcode project